# Do we need Anti Virus for Lumia 920?

Tags: settings, security

I recently bought Lumia 920, just want to know that if any Anti-virus is must for this phone or I can use it peacefully without anti-virus? If required then which one?

Answer (score 23):

No you do not need an anti-virus. Actually there is no anti-viruses for Windows Phone 8 as of now.

Unlike Android for example, there is no alternative app stores where you can download untrusted-unverified applications. All applications for WP are verified by Microsoft before going public, hence there is no need for an anti-virus. In addition to that each application has a limited access to the device/storage as a part of the security in WP8.

Comment: Additionally, being the sandboxed platform it is, it should be impossible to create any (3rd party) antivirus for WP (if you could, then you also could create a virus or at least snooping malware).

Comment: i just sent a picture to my friend and my lumia 920 got frozen.is it virus or what?

Comment: @ziggie it was sent via O.S. or a particular app? Is not common Lumia devices freezing even with app.